# Creating a dynamic gallery in React Native, but images will not appear

Tags: json, react-native

I am trying to create a dynamic photo gallery for all the characters on my app.  When I click on the gallery for that particular character, It takes me to their gallery, but no images appear. Each character should have 3 images for their gallery. While the app does not break, I do get a warning message saying the following: "Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `image`."  Can somebody look at my code and see where I am wrong?

I created a JSON file with images for each character.

```
//CharacterImages.js   
 const CharacterImages = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Homer Simpson",
        urlone:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/f1/36/ca/f136ca04817e60fa12f4a5680101ff8b.jpg",
        urltwo:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b1/da/e2/b1dae2fe6ca1620e5d1949a2dcd33a0c.jpg",
        urlthree:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/7b/53/32/7b5332ef6a981b3c54e855495ea1c828.jpg"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "Marge Simpson",
        urlone:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/63/e4/7d/63e47d98e66622bbff5e4578ccffeffc.jpg",
        urltwo:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/04/48/60/044860ebcd5d6c14a1140b351cb620b1.jpg",
        urlthree:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6d/99/26/6d9926fa54bc3650acf9295d997fc72c.jpg"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Bart Simpson",
        urlone:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/fe/18/af/fe18af309234936e231fa107c6d2b4c7.jpg",
        urltwo:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/20/59/7a/20597ab32ab0f7ec8a5484fa384e0bb4.jpg",
        urlthree:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/20/59/7a/20597ab32ab0f7ec8a5484fa384e0bb4.jpg"
      }

    export default CharacterImages;
```

I created a separate folder so that the images can come in dynamically.

```
// ImageGallery.js
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
    import { SliderBox } from "react-native-image-slider-box";
    import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
    import CharacterImages from "../Data/CharacterImages";

    class ImageGallery extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Gallery",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#53b4e6"
        },
        headerTintColor: "#f6c945",
        headerTitleStyle: "bold"
      };
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          CharacterImages
        };
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <SliderBox
              images={this.state.CharacterImages}
              sliderBoxHeight={900}
              onCurrentImagePressed={index =>
                console.warn(`image ${index} pressed`)
              }
              dotColor="yellow"
              inactiveDotColor="white"
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1
      }
    });
    export default withNavigation(ImageGallery);
```

Finally, the user can access the each characters gallery when they are in that particular profile this way:

```
//CharacterProfile.js    
headerRight: (
          <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ImageGallery")}
            title="Gallery"
            color="#f6c945"
          />
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are passing a whole object of datas instead of an array of strings with urls.

Try changing `images` prop to:

```
images = {this.state.CharacterImages.urlone}
```

Then i would advise to create a single  "image" key object with the array of strings, making your CharacterImages be:

```
const CharacterImages = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Homer Simpson",
        images:["https://i.pinimg.com/474x/f1/36/ca/f136ca04817e60fa12f4a5680101ff8b.jpg",
          "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b1/da/e2/b1dae2fe6ca1620e5d1949a2dcd33a0c.jpg",
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/7b/53/32/7b5332ef6a981b3c54e855495ea1c828.jpg"]
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "Marge Simpson",
        images:["https://i.pinimg.com/564x/63/e4/7d/63e47d98e66622bbff5e4578ccffeffc.jpg",
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/04/48/60/044860ebcd5d6c14a1140b351cb620b1.jpg",
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6d/99/26/6d9926fa54bc3650acf9295d997fc72c.jpg"]
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Bart Simpson",
        images:["https://i.pinimg.com/564x/fe/18/af/fe18af309234936e231fa107c6d2b4c7.jpg",
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/20/59/7a/20597ab32ab0f7ec8a5484fa384e0bb4.jpg",
          "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/20/59/7a/20597ab32ab0f7ec8a5484fa384e0bb4.jpg"]
      }
```

]
        export default CharacterImages;

EDIT

Forgot that CharacterImages is an Array of objects!!!
I updated also the constant as i didn't close the array

Here you have to decide how you want to render your images based of which condition. I'm going to show you how to put them so all images gets rendered:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    mergedArray=CharacterImages.map(item=> item.images).concat.apply([], mergedArray)

    this.state={
        images=mergedArr
    }    
}
```

After this you can use `this.state.images` inside your `SliderBox`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but now I am getting an error message saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.  I wonder why that is...

Comment: did you change this.state.CharacterImages.urlone to this.state.CharacterImages.images?

Comment: I did.  It is currently like this images = { this.state.images}

Comment: If you are using the code I did it’s “this.state.CharacterImages.images” inside the sliderBox

Comment: I do have that.  I wonder if it's how I have the state set up in the constructor?

Comment: Edit my question!